Unable to create GCP Composer environment
Unable to create GCP Composer environment - "Some of the GKE pods failed to become healthy". How to resolve this? I have configured the setting and gave the necessary access. But it failed to create the environment. Can anyone help into this?
I have configured the setting and gave the necessary access. But it failed to create the environment. Can anyone help into this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community this is a no-code operation. I can reproduce (and did reproduce like 20 times). It is at the moment not possible for me to create a cluster using default parameters (and it's infuriating). Logs say that service-xxx@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com is missing roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext but this SA is supposed to be created during the Cluster's creation.

I'm assuming you're trying to create a Composer 2 environment.
You might have insufficient resource quotas
The first thing you need to do is to check your quotas and increase them if needed. It seems that the default GCP quotas might not be sufficient to run a small Composer cluster.
You might have insufficient access rights
At the time of writing, there's a missing access right for version 2 that you need to add to the Google-managed service account, which is not automatically granted at environment creation. Here is the documentation about Cloud Composer access control.

This requires iam.serviceAccounts.getIamPolicy and iam.serviceAccounts.setIamPolicy permissions, which are provided by the Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension (roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext) role.


This role is not granted automatically. You must grant it manually. For instructions on granting this role, see Grant required permissions to Cloud Composer service account.

You can observe Google-managed Service Accounts and change their roles and permissions using IAM Admin.

By default, Google-managed service accounts also aren't listed in the IAM page in the Google Cloud console, even if they've been granted a role on your project. To view role grants for Google-managed service accounts, select the Include Google-provided role grants checkbox.

Conclusion
You need to grant roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext to the Cloud Composer Service Agent Service Account which has an e-mail address like:
service-<PROJECT_ID>@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Here's the link to grant the permission

At the time of writing this, I found GCP Composer 2 environments no longer work with the default settings fundamentally by 2 reasons:

The roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext role is not granted to the Cloud Composer Service Agent account (the Google-managed one): you have to set it manually.
Any environment works with the "Small" configuration of resources size: you have to select at least "Medium" or a "Custom" large enough one.
However, within this configuration, the default quota limits are exceeded. In particular, those regarding "Persistent Disk SSD (GB)" (and maybe "CPUs") of the 'Compute Engine Service'. Thus, you have to request to increase them; personally, I expanded the following quotas:

Persistent Disk SSD (GB): 500 GB -> 1 TB
CPUs (region ): 32 -> 128
CPUs (all regions): 32 -> 128



Hope this helps!
